# Match contents of one file with the contents of a second file

Tags: python

I want to match column one content of file1 with the elements of file2, and then output the the four column contents of file 1:

How can I change my code (below) to get the required output from my input files:

my code:

```
infile1=open("file1.txt","r")
infile2=open("file2","r")

outfile=open("out.txt","w")
for file2 in infile2:
    file2=file2.rstrip()
    print file2
    for file1 in infile1:
        file1=file1.rstrip().split("\t")
        print file1[3]
        if file1[3].strip()==file2.rstrip():
        if file2.rstrip() in file1[3]:
        print file1
        #outfile.write("\t".join(file1[0],file1[1],file1[2]] + "\n"))
        outfile.write("\n".join(file1.rstrip() for file1 in infile1))
```

infile1:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
1   20  H-H UU_290
1   15  GB  XX_245
3   16  GB  UM_790
3   16  G-B2    UM_791
4   16  MM  UX_234
```

infile2:

```
XX_245
UM_790
```

outfile:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
1   15  GB  XX_245
3   16  GB  UM_790
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
infile1=open("file1.txt","r")
infile2=open("file2","r")
import re
outfile=open("out.txt","w")
for file1 in infile1:

    print file1
    for file2 in infile2:
         print file2
         if re.findall(r"(?<=[ ])"+file2+"\n$",file1):
              outfile.write(file1)
```

You can simply do this using `re`.